# Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I am new to all of this Linux based OS. Can I upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS OS to Ubuntu 12.10 and if so how do I go about doing that? I tried going through the update manager but the upgrade tab is not available after all updates are complete.

Comment: 2) If you decide to ask a question, please use a more specific title.

Answer (score 0):

The below link will provides you with the information to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10.

[Quantal Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/QuantalUpgrades)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can upgrade your system from LTS version to non-LTS version. but first you must select "For any new version" in software-sources -> update tab.
you can open software sources by going to ubuntu software center -> edit -> software sources